# Как добавить стикер с анимацией в приложение на android?

Tags: java, android, telegram

Мне нужна помощь в добавлении стикера с анимацией из телеграма.

Comment: а вы что-то искали в данном направлении? результаты какие-то есть? желательно поделиться наработками :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как в вопросе нет никаких уточнений, то можно совсем заморочиться, если это единоразово нужно.

1. Скачать стикеры из Телеграм в формате .tgs (тут рассказывается, как это сделать - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8ygQ0J33kw)
2. Сконвертировать .tgs в .gif, например, с помощью этого бота: https://ru.botostore.com/c/tgstogifbot/
3. Добавить gif в Activity например вот так: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pv-EGjMI7jU